# Autoinstaller for windows applications?

Tags: python, windows

How to code an autoinstaller for any application? Suppose I have got the firefox installer, so I want to run my .py file and it will automatically install firefox on my computer.

Comment: you basically are asking how you can launch an exe with python?

Comment: Not at all, then it will automatically install the application, I mean: automatically run the "steps" for installing the "application".

Comment: Your comment makes your question make even less sense... I'm now completely lost as to what you want to do

Comment: For example: I run MyProgram.py then it will automatically install firefox, Do I explain myself?

Comment: you want your program to automatically simulate user inputs while installing, correct?

Comment: Correct... I want my program to do that...

Comment: Ahh huh! You might care to make that a bit clearer in your question! There's http://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/ - but that'll require work on your part working out the actions to make it perform - but also a lot of installers will take command line arguments to do "un-supervised" installs - so you may find what you're trying to do is fairly redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for to autoinstall Firefox using python you can just do this:

```
import urllib, os
urllib.urlretrieve("https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-17.0.1&os=win&lang=en-US", "Firefox.exe")
os.system("Firefox.exe /S")
```

You don't have to use `os.system` but you get the general idea.
For more info on silent installing Firefox, see here: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Installer:Command_Line_Arguments

Answer (score 0):

Try out [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.googlecode.com/hg/pywinauto/docs/contents.html#contents-root) or automating [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)'s COM server through [win32com](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/docindex.html)